# QGIS - Average a DEM into a single, flat plane

Tags: qgis, dem, xyz

I have a XYZ point cloud that I am interpolating into a DEM. The data represents a surface that is relatively flat. I am hoping to be able to create a DEM of a single flat plane that best represents the input DEM.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are the XYZ points irregular or regular? Do you have 'noise' (trees, buildings etc..) in your point cloud?

Comment: What do you expect as a result? A Digital elevation model of the ground? If your points are unfiltered (even if the area is flat), much of the returns (assuming it's lidar), would come from non-ground objects (bushes, trees etc.). So if your data is not pre-processed, you might need to separate ground from non-ground returns first.

Comment: the points are irregular - no real noise, it represents a single surface which is a large roof in this case. Abnormalities such as roof vents, antennas etc have been removed manually. As a result I would like a DEM of a single, flat plane, that best represents the input point data

Comment: So your end goal is to get a mean elevation of the roof?

Comment: No, picture the roof being on a 10 degree angle - I want a DEM that represents this flat, 10 degree plane - sorry, my description is far for easy to understand!

Comment: I realised I was approaching this entirely wrong. What I was looking at doing was creating a best fit plane on the original point cloud data which I am able to do very efficiently in CloudCompare. Thanks for you comments